# Microscopic explanation for the linear relationship between the Coulomb potential and the effective Coulomb potential

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge, polarization, coulombs-law

The Coulomb potential a distance $r$ from a point charge $q$ is
$$
\phi = \frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\frac{q}{r}\,.
$$
Here $\varepsilon_0$ is the permittivity of vacuum. Now assume that there are dipolar molecules surrounding the point charge. These dipolar molecules are allowed to orient themselves freely at given temperature $T$. The polarization of the point charge leads to a shielding of the potential from the central ion. Then the effective potential of the Coulomb potential is

$$
\phi^\text{eff} = \frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_r\varepsilon_0}\frac{q}{r}\,.
$$
Here $\varepsilon_r$ is the relative permittivity. I know that there exists an empirical argument that this is valid for materials that are electrically linear. In other words, the second equation is valid for materials that satisfy $\mathbf{P}=\varepsilon_r \mathbf{E}$. Here $\mathbf{P}$ is the polarization and $\mathbf{E}$ is the electric field (https://web.mit.edu/6.013_book/www/chapter6/6.4.html). I am, however, not looking for an empirical explanation.

I am struggling with the *microscopic* intuition for why the effective potential differs from the Coulomb potential by a proportionality constant $1/\varepsilon_r$. Why is there a linear relationship between the two cases (microscopically)? The potential from a point-dipole scales according to $r^{-3}$. How can molecules with potentials that scale according to $r^{-3}$ lead to a linear decrease in the effective Coulomb potential?

I am looking for either an explanation or a good reference.

Comment: All EM textbooks on the level of Griffiths or above start the chapter on dielectrics by deriving the macroscopic equation for P from averages over microscopic dipoles.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbf{P}=\varepsilon_r\mathbf{E}$ is an approximation, which works rather well in many situations, but which is neither general, nor always applicable. In some important cases the media response might be *non-local* and/or *non-linear*. I fact, spatial and temporal non-locality is usually accounted for already in the basic linear response theories (such as Kubo formula, Kramers-Krönig relations, etc.) constant susceptibility and permittivity are a feature of the introductory electrodynamic courses... although, it is worth repeating, that in many real-life situations this approximation is sufficient.

I suggest [this answer for a bit more detailed discussion (with equations)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/719209/247642).

**Remarks:**

- calling the effective potential equation *microscopic* is not quite a standard terminoligy, since screend potential is *macroscopic* - the polarization is averaged over a *physically small volume*. Indeed, the real electric field and potential vary greatly on microscopic distances, as we move from one molecule to another.
- You might be interested in reading about [Debye screening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_length), which converts Coulomb potential in Yukava-like shape, i.e., manifestly non-linear relationship between the two.

Comment: I agree that saying that the effective potential is microscopic is confusing.

Comment: I guess what I am asking is how do the dipolar molecules align themselves (on average) such that $\mathbf{P}=\varepsilon_r \mathbf{E}$. For me this relationship is not intuitive. 

Which molecular configurations contribute for $\phi^\text{eff}$ to be valid? For instance, I assume that $\mathbf{P}=\varepsilon_r \mathbf{E}$ is only valid if there are sufficiently many polar molecules (on average) between the point charge and a point a distance $r$ away. What other restrictions are there on the microscopic description of the solvent?

Comment: In Debye screening $\phi^\text{eff}$ is used in the derivation to estimate the effective Coulomb interaction between an ion and its ionic atmosphere. Here the solvent is modeled as a continuum with a permittivity $\varepsilon_r$. For what kind of solvent would we expect the derivation to be valid?

Comment: @LodinEllingsen the molecules align along the electric field lines. But averaging is the key here: if you simply consider a bunch of molecules aligned along the electric field lines the field will vary significantly in space, it will be nothing like the effective potential.

Comment: If there is a tendency (on average) for the molecules to align themselves along the electric field lines, why does this lead to a linear relationship?